# Should I deposit 0.01 bitcoins?

Tags: transactions

I recently won 0.32 in bitcoins as I have been getting into [NFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fungible_token#Description). I wanted to sell the bitcoins that I won, but in order for me to withdraw the bitcoins it’s asking me to deposit 0.01 bitcoins. Is this process usually like this?

The website is [www.recrypto.com](http://www.recrypto.com). Would it be smart if I invest in the 0.01 bitcoin to be able to withdraw it all (as the 0.01 deposit is just a verification step)? I would then withdraw 0.33 bitcoins.

Answer (score 18):

I'm sorry to say this is a scam.  Put it in dollar terms.  Someone is telling you that you've won a surprise $20,000 (not very believable in the first place).  But to get it, you have to send $600 for "verification" -- what possible reason could there be for this except to enrich the scammer?  They'll never send the $20,000, and you'll be out the $600.   (If you send the $600, they may try to  finagle more money from you until you eventually give up on ever getting the non-existent "prize  money".)

Comment: "what possible reason could there be for this except to enrich the scammer" - It would verify that the address is controlled by OP.  So the .33 bitcoin is sure to go to the correct receipient.

Of course 1 Satoshi would be sufficient if that was the actual goal.

Comment: @Taemyr it is possible to prove ownership of an address, for free, by signing a message with the address's private key. Most bitcoin wallets come with this feature as standard.

Comment: AKA the [advance-fee scam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam) AKA the Nigerian prince scam.

Answer (score 4):

No, you should not deposit .01 bitcoins. This is well known fraud